# How to reference the absolute directory of a project in Autoconf (to call custom scripts in portable way)?

Tags: scripting, portability, autoconf

I'm writing a custom check for installed libraries in autoconf:

```
AC_DEFUN([AC_GHC_PKG_CHECK],[
    ...
    GHC_PKG_RESULT=$($PYTHON autotools/check-ghc-version-range ....)
    ...
])
```

where my Python script that actually performs the check resides in the `autotools/` sub-directory of the project.

However, this is not portable, for example `make dist-check` fails because then autoconf tools are called from a different directory. How can I reference the absolute path to my Python script so that it gets called properly no matter what the current directory is?

Answer (score 0):

`ac_top_srcdir` or `ac_abs_top_srcdir` should work in this case:

```
AC_DEFUN([AC_GHC_PKG_CHECK],[
    ...
    GHC_PKG_RESULT=$($PYTHON $ac_top_srcdir/autotools/check-ghc-version-range ....)
    ...
])
```

EDIT:  I don't think this approach will work -- it seems that `$ac_top_srcdir` aren't evaluated until later (`AC_OUTPUT`?).

What I think might work in this instance is to do something similar to what the runtime C tests do:  blast a configuration test to a temporary file (`conftest.py` instead of `conftest.c` in this case) and run it.  Unfortunately, there's (yet) no builtin macros or for automake/autoconf other tools that directly assist with this task.

Fortunately it seems that [a clever person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626998/brandon-invergo) has written at least a couple different ways to do this.  The first one is [GNU pyconfigure](http://www.gnu.org/software/pyconfigure/) which seems to have [facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/pyconfigure/manual/pyconfigure.html#Writing-test-programs) for writing Python test code as I described above.  The second one is more of an [ad hoc macro collection](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2012-09/msg00044.html) that he used for his project.

Comment: For some strange reason these variables aren't set in my configure.ac. For example if I try `AC_MSG_NOTICE(PATH: $ac_abs_top_srcdir)` or `AC_MSG_NOTICE(PATH: $ac_top_srcdir)` then nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$srcdir`.

It's not necessarily an absolute path, but it's a path that points from the top of the build tree to the top of the source tree.